# Conditional Validation of ViewModels

Tags: asp.net, validation, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I have a ViewModel which is used for a Wizard containing two separate ViewModels which are used to load partial views into the wizard. Depending on the option selected on Step1, I need to validate either Step2 or Step3. The viewmodels for Step2 and 3 have their own AbstractValidator which works great because it includes client side validation. The problem is that if I use ModelState.IsValid, one of the VMs always fails to validate because it's empty (that step was not filled out). Is there a way to skip validation for one of the viewmodels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually arrived at was surprisingly simple but I didn't spot it in the docs. You can call `$('#somecontainer').valid()` which will show validation messages for supported controls and also return `true` if all controls in the container are valid. It doesn't work for everything as rules like `GreaterThan` aren't supported client side.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the following model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

But you want to exclude FullName from the model validation because you are using the model also in a place where FullName is not filled in, you can do so in the following way:

```
ModelState.Remove("FullName");
```

Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Thanks. That kind of works, but both of my ViewModels are quite long, I also can't use this for client side validation. Ideally I'd like the validator to just check the controls inside a container element but I don't see any way of doing that without writing a tonne of custom code.

Comment: @Echilon: Hi, my friend. This solution is not best, but I think it's quite too easy to apply :D